# Did not receive rep for 4 upvotes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Strange one...

I received four upvotes and my answer was accepted, but I have yet to receive any rep points for it.  I did get the +15 for being the accepted answer, but I never got the +40 for the upvotes.

[run-time const to define array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812726/run-time-const-to-define-array-size/9812781#comment12499754_9812781)

Anyway, thought this may be a bug you guys want to know about.

Comment: Congratulations - [you hit the rep cap for today](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1053/ed-s?tab=reputation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reached the reputation cap, you can only get a maximum of 200 rep from upvotes in a given day.

Comment: ...d'oh, totally forgot about the cap. :D  Thanks